# How to add several Checkboxs columns

Tags: wpf, listview

I have `ListView` binding with my collection:

```
private List<MyData> Col;

ItemsSource="{Binding Col}"
```

I define this inside my `ListView`:

```
<ListView.View>
                <GridView>
                    <GridView.Columns>
                        <GridViewColumn Header="Selected">
                            <GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                                <DataTemplate>
                                    <CheckBox x:Name="cbSelect" IsChecked="{Binding SupportedVendors}" />
                                </DataTemplate>
                            </GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                        </GridViewColumn>
                        <GridViewColumn DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Name}" Header="Name" Width="100"/>
                        <GridViewColumn DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding ID}" Header="ID" Width="600"/>
                    </GridView.Columns>
                </GridView>
            </ListView.View>
```

Now i want channge my object bool value inside my Collcection once the user change the `CheckBox`.
I can i do that ? (i need it in code behaind)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tag the object of your collection with the CheckBox, the on check /uncheck you can get the tag from the checkbox checked. Change the bool value in the object.